# Add additional operations to existing method which is in Python module

Tags: python-3.x, methods, extending

I have a python module which has several methods:

module.py

```
def a():
   return "This is a method"
```

I want to add some additional functionality to method a by calling it from script to avoid modification in module itself.

How can I add additional operations or arguments to that module calling it from script? 
For example I imported module.py in my script and in that script I add two arguments to method "a" and addition of those arguments in addition to:

```
return "This is a method"
```

Comment: One more thing though: you should note that in python **functions** are usually referred to as **methods** only when they are part of a **class**. If they are standalone functions they are usually referred to as.. functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you cannot really change any imported methods as far as I am aware. That does not mean it is completely impossible, I just wouldn't know how.

Question is though if that is actually what you want (as I believe it is a very uncommon way of handling code and I am guessing not an advisable one)?

Could it be that what you actually want to achieve is something more like this:

**module_script.py**

```
def a(variable):
   return_value = "This is a " + str(variable) + " method!"
   return return_value
```

**second_script.py**

```
import module_script

print(module_script.a("nice"))
```

The output of the second script would be:

```
"This is a nice method!"
```